# Classification report returns same accuracy precision recall averages at binary classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification

My results are:

[image]

This is the Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report

df = pd.read_csv(dataset)
X = df.drop(columns=['backers_count','converted_pledged_amount','pledged'
      ,'id','usd_pledged','state','static_usd_rate','funded_percentage'])
y = df['state'].values
# Split dataset into train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42,stratify=y)

# Create Logistic Regression Classifier
logreg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',max_iter=400)
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)  
log_predict = logreg.predict(X_test)

#train model with cv of 10
cv_scores = cross_val_score(logreg, X, y, cv=10)

# Print the results
print("=== Confusion Matrix ===")
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, log_predict))
print('\n')
print("=== Classification Report ===")
print(classification_report(y_test, log_predict))
print('\n')
print("=== All Accuracy Scores ===")
print(cv_scores)
print('\n')
print("=== Mean Accuracy Score ===")
print("Mean Accuracy Score - Logistic Regression: ", cv_scores.mean())
```

Is it normal to have identical values to micro avgs macro avgs and weighted for precision recall f1-score and to accuracy as well or there's something wrong with my model? This also happens(getting identical results to precision recall f1-score accuracy) at other classification models with the same dataset that I've tried like random forest and SVC. If its normal how do I interpret this, or is it just wrong code and try to fix this?

Which avg matters and should record for binary classification(micro macro or weighted) or all?

Comment: what problem are you referring to? what do you mean by "this"?

Comment: Is it normal to have identical values to micro avgs macro avgs and weighted for precision recall f1-score and to accuracy as well or there's something wrong with my model? This also happens at other classification models with the same dataset that I've tried like random forest and SVC.

Comment: I think that you can try after removing that random_state argument in the train_test_split. The seed must be generating the same train_test splits, eventually giving out the exact same results for each run.

Comment: I will try this, thank you

Comment: I got the same results even after removing that line, also same accuracy scores identical. My confusion matrix did change though

Comment: Accuracy is somewhat not going to change a lot, because the dataset is imbalanced with more number of 1s. In the scenarios where there is a class imbalance, accuracy isn't a favorable metric. Consider your F1-Score instead, and you should see variations in the F1-score.

Comment: well my dataset is 40%-60% which makes it a balanced dataset,am I wrong?

Comment: Although this ratio might not look very imbalanced to us in general, but it still leaves a room for bias, and even if your model predicts all instances to be 1, it still is going to give you roughly a 60% accuracy, which is not a lot less than what you're currently getting in your results. Strictly theoretically speaking, you should prefer f1 over accuracy. In simpler words, you're 60% correct and 40% wrong...

Comment: What about the fact that my micro macro and weighted averages for precision recall and f1-score that are almost identical is this something to worry about? I can't interpret this, accuracy seems to be identical as well with micro avgs. Also when you mean to calculate the f1-score I should calculate it with cross_val_score(logreg,X,y,cv = 10, scoring='f1') or the weighted, micro avgs are enough ?